# Help disabling calendar pop up

Tags: aura, lightninginput, date-picker

My client wants to use the date type on a lightning:input component, but wants the date picker calendar disabled.

I have tried toying with the CSS, but that really isn't my strength. They're unwilling to use the ui:input date picker that is out there (even though has an attribute that would let me disable the calendar pop up).

```
<lightning:input aura:id="dealerLicenseExpireDateInput" 
   type="date" 
   name="Exp_Date__c" 
   requiredLabel="true" 
   required="true"
   label="Expiration Date" 
   messageWhenValueMissing="Expiration Date is required"
   value="{!v.app.Exp_Date__c}" 
   min="{!v.currentDate}"
   messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Expiration Date can not be in the past" 
   onblur="{!c.doValid}"/>
```

[image: img of date picker]

Comment: figured it out. adding this to the style disabled the calendar, but the user can still type in a date. 

`.THIS .slds-datepicker{
    display: none !important;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. adding this to the style sheet disabled the calendar, but the user can still type in a date.

`.THIS .slds-datepicker{ display: none !important; }`